# Exim sending got very slow

Tags: linux, exim

About 2 days ago the load averages on my server got really high and I was able to isolate the issue to slow exim sending causing iowaits.

I am now trying to figure out how to fix the issue.

I ran this and can see the sending significantly slowed from about 1s per email to 10-20s per email:

```
cat exim_mainlog | grep "Completed QT=" | tail
```

I updated this exim settings to:

```
rfc1413_query_timeout = 0s
```

as per other questions, but this did not help. I thought it can be a disk issue with spooling, but it looks like the queue call is fast.

Here is the log of a single message - it looks like the outbound SMTP takes a long time. What does this mean? What exactly does this step do, and how can it be lowered?

```
2019-06-14 04:51:35.895 [16331] 1hbkjs-0004FP-PQ <= emails@****.com H=localhost (server.****.com) [127.0.0.1]:24868 I=[127.0.0.1]:25 P=esmtpa L- A=dovecot_login:emails@****.com S=5844 M8S=0 RT=2.571s id=bbd815677983ad92d1345cb071e45fdf@server.******.com T="Email Subject" from <emails@*****.com> for ******@hotmail.com
2019-06-14 04:51:35.904 [16334] cwd=/var/spool/exim 3 args: /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1hbkjs-0004FP-PQ
2019-06-14 04:51:35.935 [16334] 1hbkjs-0004FP-PQ Sender identification U=daniel D=*****.com S=emails@*****.com
2019-06-14 04:51:35.936 [16334] 1hbkjs-0004FP-PQ SMTP connection outbound 1560513095 1hbkjs-0004FP-PQ ******.com *****@hotmail.com
2019-06-14 04:51:42.363 [16334] 1hbkjs-0004FP-PQ => *****@hotmail.com F=<emails@****.com> P=<emails@*****.com> R=dkim_lookuphost T=dkim_remote_smtp S=7260 H=hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com [104.47.13.33]:25 I=[1.2.3.4]40283 X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:256 CV=yes DN="/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=mail.protection.outlook.com" L C="250 2.6.0 <bbd815677983ad92d1345cb071e45fdf@server.****.com> [InternalId=43731357090107, Hostname=HE1EUR04HT131.eop-eur04.prod.protection.outlook.com] 14909 bytes in 0.364, 39.896 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery -> 250 2.1.5" QT=17s DT=2.656s
2019-06-14 04:51:42.363 [16334] 1hbkjs-0004FP-PQ Completed QT=17s
```

Comment: You should remove any `rfc1413_hosts` entries, so that exim doesn't try an ident callout at all; it doesn't really help anything nowadays. Anyway, that would only be a wait on the network, delaying *reception* of email, and not sending, and would not have any impact on IO traffic. You need to figure out what is causing the IO load. Are your disks OK (no bad sectors causing blocking retries, for example), that type of thing?

Comment: Is it definitely stuck on the part before sending? What part of the sending can be OP blocked?